# C++ Splitting vector of vectors into N-many sub-vectors of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, split

I have a very large vector of vectors that I want to split into N-many sub-vectors (of vectors) via a function. The function will then perform some algorithmic routines on these sub-vectors but not return anything. I know how many sub-vectors (of vectors) that I want to split the original vector of vectors into (although NOT at compile time), and I am not sure how I am to create N-many sub-vectors of vectors within the function at runtime.

Usually, if you are splitting a vector into n-many sub-vectors, you would create a vector of vectors to store each sub-vector, especially if you require that the scope of these sub-vectors extends beyond the loop you are using to perform the splitting. Am I looking for (for lack of better description) a "four dimensional vector" to store these sub-vectors of vectors?

To clarify, say I have a vector of vectors that looks like so:

```
vec = { {945,1,1.0882222739646},
        {955,1,1.08030633720477},
        {965,1,1.06095611392935},
        {975,1,1.0736443050851},
        {985,1,1.04649065403142},
        {995,1,1.06294684603874},
        {1005,1,1.065654589561},
        {1015,1,1.0668922119373},
        {1025,1,1.03109676962124},
        {1035,1,1.08430139146623} }
```

and I want to split it into 5 (determined at runtime) sub-vectors of vectors like so:

```
vec1 = { {945,1,1.0882222739646},
         {955,1,1.08030633720477} }

vec2 = { {965,1,1.06095611392935},
         {975,1,1.0736443050851} }

vec3 = { {985,1,1.04649065403142},
        {995,1,1.06294684603874} }

vec4 = { {1005,1,1.065654589561},
        {1015,1,1.0668922119373} }

vec5 = { {1025,1,1.03109676962124},
        {1035,1,1.08430139146623} }
```

How exactly does one go about this? My function so far looks like so:

```
void calc_frac_block (vector<vector <double> > conc_data, vector<int> expidx)
{
   // First, we need to create n-many vectors of vectors corresponding to the size of expidx
   int expidx_size = expidx.size();

   cout << "Size of expidx is: " << expidx_size << endl;

   // Now we find the size of each subvector of vectors by diving conc_data by expidx_size
   int subvec_size = conc_data.size() / expidx_size;   // Will always be a whole number

   cout << "Size of each subvector is: " << subvec_size << endl;

   // NOW I HAVE THE NUMBER OF SUB-VECTORS OF VECTORS AND THE SIZE OF EACH... HOW TO PROCEED?

}
```

Any pointers would be helpful. I am using C++11 so solutions involving features therein are acceptable ;)

Comment: is expidx the number of elements in each of the n subvectors

Comment: expidx is the number of subvectors that the original vector of vectors is split into and subvec_size is the number of vectors within each vector of vectors that result from the splitting.

Comment: Is the subvec_size value correct?

Comment: From what is passed to the function so far, both epidx and subvec_size are resulting in the correct values that I desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your vector in a loop

```
vector<vector<vector <double>>> sub_vectors;
for (std::size_t i(0); i < expidx_size; ++i) {
    sub_vectors.emplace_back(vec.begin() + i * subvec_size, vec.begin() + (i + 1) * subvec_size);
}
```

Here is an example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec = { {945,1,1.0882222739646},
        {955,1,1.08030633720477},
        {965,1,1.06095611392935},
        {975,1,1.0736443050851},
        {985,1,1.04649065403142},
        {995,1,1.06294684603874},
        {1005,1,1.065654589561},
        {1015,1,1.0668922119373},
        {1025,1,1.03109676962124},
        {1035,1,1.08430139146623} };

    int expidx_size(5);
    std::cout << "Size of expidx is: " << expidx_size << std::endl;

    int subvec_size = vec.size() / expidx_size;

    std::cout << "Size of each subvector is: " << subvec_size << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector <double>>> sub_vectors;
    for (std::size_t i(0); i < expidx_size; ++i) {
            sub_vectors.emplace_back(vec.begin() + i * subvec_size, vec.begin() + (i + 1) * subvec_size);
    }

    for (std::size_t i(0); i < expidx_size; ++i) {
        for (const auto& sub_vector : sub_vectors[i]) {
            std::cout << "{ ";
            for (const auto& value : sub_vector) {
                std::cout << value << " ";
            }

            std::cout << " }";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```